# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute ‘group’ {for instagram}

Tags: python

```
Lokesh-mac-mini-pro-2:instabot.py-master Lokeshmacminipro$ python example.py
02.09.2018_10:03 Instabot v1.2.0 started at 02.09.2018 10:03:

02.09.2018_10:03 Trying to login as moneshrallapalli...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 52, in <module>
    unfollow_whitelist=['example_user_1', 'example_user_2'])
  File "/Users/lokemone/Desktop/instabot.py-master/src/instabot.py", line 234, in __init__
    self.login()
  File "/Users/lokemone/Desktop/instabot.py-master/src/instabot.py", line 303, in login
    self.user_id = ui.get_user_id_by_login(self.user_login)
  File "/Users/lokemone/Desktop/instabot.py-master/src/userinfo.py", line 42, in get_user_id_by_login
    json_info = json.loads(re.search('{"activity.+show_app', info.text, re.DOTALL).group(0)+'":""}')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Lokesh-mac-mini-pro-2:instabot.py-master Lokeshmacminipro$
```

please tell how to avoid

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute ‘group'

Comment: Can you please add your code?

Comment: The error means that your regular expression search did not match anything, so `.group` doesn't exist.

Comment: The specific reason is the pattern you are searching is not in the string. But, I guess, this happened because you were failed to properly place the curly braces and quotes in that statement. I have added a broader answer about how to solve this.

Comment: Lokesh-mac-mini-pro-2:instabot.py-master Lokeshmacminipro$ python example.py
02.09.2018_10:24 Instabot v1.2.0 started at 02.09.2018 10:24:

Comment: Take a look [at here](https://github.com/instabot-py/instabot.py/commit/806e09414f73a461bdb81fd6d4fc2e1e34a54ef8) or copy this `json_info = json.loads(re.search(r'>window._sharedData = (.*?);</script>', info.text, re.DOTALL).group(1))` and replace it with the one on `line 42` in `src/userinfo.py`

Answer (score 0):

This error means the value does not contain anything i.e. It has None values. Check it before grouping.

Answer (score 0):

It is evident from the traceback that the below line is responsible for the exception.

```
json_info = json.loads(re.search('{"activity.+show_app', info.text, re.DOTALL).group(0)+'":""}')
```

It looks like you are trying to fetch some specific things from the `info.text` and then make a json with it. In that case, your approach needs a little modification.

Let's first fix the search part. It should be,

```
matched_string = re.search('activity.+show_app', info.text, re.DOTALL).group(0)
```

The specific Exception you are getting is because of this line. The pattern you were searching was not in that string. So, you can just add a try/catch or if/else there to avoid that scenario.

Then make it a valid json explicitly, by doing:

```
 valid_json = "{" + matched_string + ": ''}"
```

Finally, load it with `json` module.

```
 valid_dict = json.loads(valid_json)
```

So, in one line, you can do,

```
try:
    some_var = json.loads("{" + re.search('activity.+show_app', info.text, re.DOTALL).group(0) + ": '' }")
except AttributeError:
    print("Couldn't find that specific pattern")
```

Hope this helps.